# linked JARs work fine in IntelliJ, but not in the command line

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I'm writing a small Java app that gets launched locally, but spawns EC2 instances. The class that I'm trying to run is `Manager`, which I wrapped into a `JAR` using a manifest file that indicates the code's entry point (`Manager.main()`), and then compiling the "Artifact" with IntelliJ.

When running the method from within IntelliJ everything works perfectly, but when trying to launch it in an EC2 instance (vis `ssh`), I get the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-61-121 ~]$ java -cp . -jar Manager.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

I also tried to manually set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to the current working directory (`/home/ec2-user`), but this essentially yields the same outcome (notice that this time I didn't specifically set the class path via the execution command):

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-61-121 ~]$ java -jar Manager.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Mind you that there's no credentials issue, I've verified this by running the class locally (I'm using IAM roles).

It's pretty clear that the error is caused because the required classes from the external `JAR`s aren't found during the loading and setup of the program from the command line, and that IntelliJ does some behind-the-scenes mumbo-jumbo that I'm unaware of.

Just to make the app's program flow clear:

1. A local class is run
2. The local class spawns a single EC2 instance for the Manager class
3. The manager class spawns multiple EC2 instances for workers that do some information analysis, and report the results back to the Manager via SQS queues.

...and if it is of any importance, my local machine uses Java 1.8.65, and the EC2 instance uses Java 1.8.73.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-cp` and `-jar` shouldn't be used together.

Either you use `-jar`, and the main class as well as the classpath must be specified in the jar manifest, or you use `-cp`, and you need to specify the classpath and the main class name.

The classpath must contain the paths to the jar files themselves, not the path to the directory containing the jar files:

```
java -cp ./file1.jar:./file2.jar com.foo.bar.MainClass
```

Relying on a global CLASSPATH environment variable is always a bad idea. Don't do that.

Comment: Well, even if I put all of the external JARs in the same folder as Manager.class, when I try to execute it via `java -cp . Manager`, I still get the same error.

Comment: Read my answer. The jar files must be in the classpath. Not the directory containing the jar files. So you should have something like `java -cp .:./file1.jar:./file2.jar Manager`

Comment: If so, why do you start the cp specification with a dot?

Comment: Because your Manager class file seems not to be in any jar file, and seems to be in the current directory. So that directory must be in the classpath too.

Comment: OK, so `java -cp .:./* Manager` works perfectly. I tried to compress all of the external JARs with Manager.class into Manager.jar (and having the relevant classpath defined in the manifest), and when trying to run `java -jar Manager.jar`, I get the same error, although relating to a different class that isn't found. Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: Your jar probably didn't have the right structure. jars inside jars are not supported, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. The issue was that , the final jar does not include all the dependent jars. But if you use maven-shaded-plugin then , the final jar will contain dependent jars too.
Below is the code . Include this in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
     <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
     <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
      <transformers>
           <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
           <mainClass>${main}</mainClass>
           </transformer>
      </transformers>
      </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

After do mvn clean insatll.
Now you will be able to run the program as jar.

Hope it helps.